# MoltenVK (for Vulkan) build failed on OS X v. 10.13.3 (17D102) | Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Tags: c++, vulkan

the problem shows up for both MoltenVK Debug and Release targets.

```
/Users/nikyotis/Developer/MoltenVK/MoltenVKShaderConverter/MoltenVKSPIRVToMSLConverter/SPIRV-Tools/source/opt/instruction.cpp:513:10: Use of undeclared identifier 'spvInstructionBinaryToText'
```

1. Maybe I should just add the header? namespace prepending does not really help...
2. Modifying the signature of `/var/instruction.h` && `/var/instruction.cpp` so that *PrettyPrint* returns void does not help either...

Self-explanatory, see images @

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

both Debug and Release build now fine

Answer (score -1):

You have some weird versioning issue.
The `instruction.cpp` linked by MoltenVK repo does not even have `PrettyPrint` function.

I would advise you to delete and clone again:
`git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK.git`

Do **not** update the submodules to `master`.

Comment: this is irrelevant: 

On Fri, Mar 9, 2018 at 3:45 PM, irobertmanley <notifications@github.com> wrote:
There are completely separate versions of instruction.cpp - one in var and one in opt. One version doesn't have it, the other does.

Comment: @NikolaosGiotis Your error message contains [/opt/instruction.cpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Tools/blob/1acce99255ee28a582776372593e91b585d3c011/source/opt/instruction.cpp). And as of now it still does not contain `spvInstructionBinaryToText` and neither `PrettyPrint` (that is unless you updated the submodules to newer version, which you should not do unless you want to experience problems).